# How to make a single static HTML webpage using Twitter Bootstrap which can show different sections as per user click

Tags: html

I am making simple website to host my profile. I used Twitter Bootstrap for layout.

I have 4 sections (A,B,C,D) in my website. I am using four different html files (i.e **A.html,B.html,C.html,D.html**) to save the corresponding text of sections. 
I have to use the same header text (for navigation) in all four html files.

Is there any way I can use only one html file i.e **index.html** and show the corresponding 
section when the user clicks on the navigation bar?

I can only use static webpages. The web-hosting service I am using only allows static pages without PHP etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options depending on what you are trying to achieve:

1. If the goal is to keep the separate content in A, B, C, and D index could use AJAX to load the content from those pages and display it. Each click in the navigation would either load the content for the first time into a `<div>` and show it, or detect that it was already loaded and show it while hiding other sections.
2. If the server supports some form of server side includes the navigation could be included into each page. There wasn't enough information in the question to determine if this would be possible.
3. Structure index.html to include all the content and only show the selected portion. This would not scale well as content size grows, and loads all the content up front, but can be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use navbar in index.html and and apply link of all 4 section like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="A.html">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="B.html">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="C.html">C</a></li>
      <li><a href="D.html">D</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image]